# SQL Native Client - how to determine if 32-bit or 64 bit is installed?

Tags: sql-server, client, windows-server-2012

we have on the server SQL Server 2012 Native Client - how to determine if version of the database client is 32bit or 64 bit?

This is very important for us because version that should be installed on that particular Windows Server **must be** 32 bit but I am not sure which version is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query on the master Db to find out what version you are running whether it is X64 (64-Bit) or X86 (32-Bit):

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Comment: this is not solution since I know that database server is 64 bit but I must check on windows server which is not database server and I do not have sql server installed there but that windows server is connected to that other database server, so basically I need to check on application server if it is 32 or 64 bits

Comment: @Dejan you are looking for info about the sql client or the server (the operating system)? from your comment it looks like you are trying to find the bitness of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Try Running this

```
    /*=============================================
  File: SQL_Server_without_AWE_WOW64_check.sql

  Author: Thomas LaRock, http://thomaslarock.com/contact-me/
  http://thomaslarock.com/2013/01/how-to-determine-if-you-are-running-a-32-bit-version-of-sql-server-on-a-64-bit-os

  Summary: This script will check to see if you have an instance of SQL
        Server 32-bit running on a 64-bit O/S without AWE enabled. 

  Date: January 9th, 2013

  SQL Server Versions: SQL2005, SQL2008, SQL2008R2, SQL2012

  You may alter this code for your own purposes. You may republish
  altered code as long as you give due credit. 

  THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY
  OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT
  LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

=============================================*/

WITH Bit_Version (os_bit_ver, sql_bit_ver, name, value_in_use)
AS
(
 SELECT RIGHT(SUBSTRING(@@VERSION, CHARINDEX('<', @@VERSION), 4), 2), 
 RIGHT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,SERVERPROPERTY('Edition'))
      , CHARINDEX('(', CONVERT(varchar,SERVERPROPERTY('Edition'))), 3), 2),
 name, value_in_use
 FROM sys.configurations
 WHERE name = 'awe enabled' 
)
SELECT CASE
 WHEN os_bit_ver = '64' AND sql_bit_ver <> '64' AND value_in_use = 0 THEN 'BAD!'
 ELSE 'GOOD!'
 END AS [IsThisABadThing]
FROM Bit_Version
```

This is not mine i got it [Here](http://thomaslarock.com/2013/01/how-to-determine-if-you-are-running-a-32-bit-version-of-sql-server-on-a-64-bit-os/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the answer can be obtained from SQL Server. It would be way simpler just to run the client application, open Task Manager, find the application process and look for `*32` suffix in the process name.

Answer (score 0):

Check this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SLQNCLI11\InstalledVersion
```

[source](http://www.mickgenie.com/how-to-check-the-version-of-sql-server-native-client/)

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question.